# Trying to change my navbar color based on time of day with javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

was looking around but couldn't find a solution. I don't know what to do and hoped someone could help me.
I keep getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined
    at header.js:7

this is my js:

```
   var today = new Date().getHours(); // Creërt een "new data object.
   var color = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');


   // colors based on time of day 
   if (today >= 18) {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
   } else if (today >= 12) {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
   } else if (today >= 0) {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
   } else {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
   }
```

here's my html just in case:

```
   <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="home.html">
        title
        </a>
    </nav>
```

and my css:

```
    .navbar {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0.5em 4em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.75);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(47, 132, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(110,236, 249, 1) 100%);}
```

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: `getVyClassName` returns an arraylike. You have to select one / all elements of that array and apply the style to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `.getElementById()` instead as this will select only one element.

The code for this will look like this.

```js
   var today = new Date().getHours(); // Creërt een "new data object.
   var color = document.getElementById('navbar');

   // colors based on time of day 
   if (today >= 18) {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
   } else if (today >= 12) {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
   } else if (today >= 0) {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
   } else {
   color.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
   }
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a href="home.html">title</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');
```

This code line returns HTMLCollection(Array). You should iterate over collection for **style.backgroundColor**

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')` returns an array. If you only have one navbar, you could use `document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0];`, which would get you the first instance, but is not the best practice.

Or, and better, you could use `document.getElementById('navbar')` and give your navbar an id of navbar instead of a class.

Hope that helps! Everything else you are doing should work.

Comment: This would help. But I use class because I want to use it on different pages.

Comment: If the pages are separate, you shouldn't have an issues with having the same Id on two pages. Try it both ways, but you usually don't want to use the `document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0]`. So is that all you need?

Comment: actually do you know how i could use a gradient color?

Comment: You should be able to use gradients just as normal, anything you can put in the HTML `style=""` tag can be applied through JS. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: I got this line of code but it doesn't seem to work:

Comment: color.style.backgroundColor = 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(47, 132, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(110, 236, 249, 1) 100%)';

Comment: Ah. Got it. Linear gradient needs to be under the `color.style.background` property not backgroundColor. That should fix it up

Comment: Great! Again thanks for your help and time. Much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah no problem, let me know if you need anything else!